# iPhone Phonegap based app load External website made of componentone

Tags: asp.net, iphone, xcode, cordova, componentone

My Client wants a native iPhone App that displays their mobile site optimized for iPhone developed using asp.net and [ComponentOnes Studio for iPhone](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/StudioiPhone/).  i was planning to use a PhoneGap app which calls an external URL using JavaScript and do it after showing the splash screen. but according to phoneGap FAQ its most likely to apple to reject an app that loads external URL ? just need somebody to clear me on the whole process. isnt it possible to create an app like that ? i've seen various iPhone apps that do this (eg: cydia).

else what care should i take if i'm to develop such an application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have answered your own question, while it is completly possible to create such an app with Phonegap, Apple isn't going to approve an app that doesn't have functionality when running unconnected (though how much functionality with Apple is never clear).  In fact, there have been at least one report on the Phonegap google groups list of app's being rejected because it was just a "[web clip](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/3487327fdd9a2781/ba2582a7c66cec15)", meaning that the app could have just been done as a website, apparently you have to add some functionality, my guess being services exposed by Phonegap, that you wouldn't be able to do on just a website..

And it is more to the point that the app that you chose to use as an example of a "web app", is only available on jailbroken phones.

Comment: hi, i just took cydia as an example coz it just came in to mind. anyway if we want an application that needs to interact with external servers? isn't this a way to go. of course i would prefer native apps. but just because my clients asking i wanted to try this. before accepting it.

what if i have some offline interface too. if there is no connectivity we show a handy message or screen saying no connection found. i guess even some native apps do this ??

Comment: I think the idea is that most of the html content should reside on the phone, and only data is used by the service.  I have no insight into Apple's app approval process, just what I have read on the Phonegap lists, Apple's website and the Phonegap FAQ.   You can certainly try it, it won't cost you anything, but I would warn clients that it may not be approved.  Also I am not saying that Native apps are the way to go, I think Phonegap is an excellent way to go, just dont think that loading a a webpage into a frame is going to get accepted.