# iOs / Phonegap: Load external mobile site?

Tags: ios5, jquery-mobile, cordova

So I've been looking at this ([iPhone Phonegap based app load External website made of componentone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457281/iphone-phonegap-based-app-load-external-website-made-of-componentone)) thread and wondering if the same still holds true today? I'm planning on making a iOs app that does little more then load an external site created with jQuery Mobile. The idea is of course to use the same site for as many plattforms as possible.

1.) If Apple will still reject apps that only redirects, is my only option to create a native iOs app?

And,

2) If not, what's the simplest solution to solve this? I've been testing with a pageinit that fires a changePage, but this isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that Apple will reject this application if it just is a native shell that redirects to a website. You can basically get the same functionality by creating a book mark on your home screen that launches your website. Expect to get the following rejection letter from Apple:

> "We've completed the review of your app but cannot post this version to the App Store because the
>   experience it provides is not sufficiently different from a web
>   browsing experience, as it would be by incorporating native iOS
>   functionality. While your app content may differ from your web site,
>   the experience it provides does not differ significantly from the
>   general experience of using Safari, as required by the App Store
>   Review Guidelines
>
> ### 12.3   Apps that are simply web clippings, content aggregators, or a collection of links, may be rejected"

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was able to confirm this with other sources as well, so I guess I'll go with another approach.